# Assembly, making a simple calculator

Tags: assembly, calculator, 8051

I'm trying to create a kind of calculator by letting LEDs burn in such a way that they represent the binary value of the addition. The program detects the right key, and does the addition. However, I would like my counter to reset after I've doen two additions, this I want to achieve by checking the status of the carry bit, which I assign to one after the first number has been seen, or at least try to. This is done in the gelezen statement, when the carry bit is not set it jumps to set and sets the bit to one and returns to start. If it is set I suppose it would skip the jump and excecute the code underneath, clearing the register R0 and setting the bit back to zero, then jumping to start.

```
            $include (c8051f120.inc)
            cseg at 0000H
            jmp     main
            cseg at 0050H

main:       clr     EA
            mov     WDTCN,#0DEh
            mov     WDTCN,#0ADh
            setb    EA
            mov     SFRPAGE,#0Fh
            mov     XBR2,#40H
            mov     P1MDOUT,#0FFH //Volledige poort als uitvoerpin
            mov     P3MDOUT,#00H //Inputpin
            mov     P0MDOUT,#0F0h // 4 in 4 uit
            clr     A
            mov     A, #0d;
            clr     c   ;
start: 
            setb    P0.5
            setb    P0.6
            setb    P0.7
            clr     P0.4
            jnb     P0.0, nol
            jnb     P0.1, vier 
            jnb     P0.2, acht
            jnb     P0.3, twaalf
            setb    P0.4
            clr     P0.5
            jnb     P0.0, een
            jnb     P0.1, vijf 
            jnb     P0.2, negen
            jnb     P0.3, dertien
            setb    P0.5
            clr     P0.6
            jnb     P0.0, twee
            jnb     P0.1, zes 
            jnb     P0.2, tien
            jnb     P0.3, veertien
            setb    P0.5
            clr     P0.7
            jnb     P0.0, drie
            jnb     P0.1, zeven 
            jnb     P0.2, elf
            jnb     P0.3, vijftien
            setb    P0.7
            jmp     start
gelezen:
            add     A, R0
            mov     P1, A
            mov     R3,#255d
loop:       mov     R1, #255d
            mov     R2, #255d
            djnz    R1,$
            djnz    R2,$
            djnz    R3,loop
            jnc     zet 
            mov     R0,#0d
            mov     A,R0
            clr     c
            jmp     start
zet:
            setb    c
            jmp     start

nol:        mov     R0, #00H
            jmp     gelezen

een:        mov     R0, #01H   
            jmp     gelezen

twee:       mov     R0, #02H      
            jmp     gelezen

drie:       mov     R0, #03H
            jmp     gelezen

vier:       mov     R0, #04H     
            jmp     gelezen

vijf:       mov     R0, #05H
            jmp     gelezen

zes:        mov     R0, #06H
            jmp     gelezen

zeven:      mov     R0, #07H
            jmp     gelezen

acht:       mov     R0, #08H
            jmp     gelezen

negen:      mov     R0, #09H
            jmp     gelezen

tien:       mov     R0, #0AH      
            jmp     gelezen

elf:        mov     R0, #0BH   
            jmp     gelezen

twaalf:     mov     R0, #0CH
            jmp     gelezen

dertien:    mov     R0, #0DH
            jmp     gelezen

veertien:   mov     R0, #0EH
            jmp     gelezen

vijftien:   mov     R0, #0FH
            jmp     gelezen
```

Comment: The `ADD` instruction overwrites carry flag of course. Use a bit variable, or a counter register.

Comment: Would that matter? If the carry bit is set either by me, or the add function it should excecute this part of the code? : 
 `mov R0,#0d
            mov A,R0
            clr c
            jmp start`

Comment: Only the `ADD` matters, whatever you did previously is overwritten by the `ADD`. That code only gets executed if there was a carry from the addition.

Comment: You have to be very careful when using the Carry Flag as your own status flag, with intimate knowledge of how other instructions affect it. If you want a counter don't try to debug the the use of the Carry - it's a loser. Use a counter in a register or a location.

Comment: There are some specific advantages to keeping your source code neatly formatted. 1) it makes it easier to follow. 2) assembler work is *precise* and that precision is likely to mirror the care and attention to the source code presentation. 3) while you are formatting the text, your attention is drawn once more to what you have actually written.